# Dissable javascript parallax effect for mobile devices

Tags: javascript, mobile, parallax, device

I have a site with a parallax effect. I want to disable this javascript for mobile devices. In antoher post I saw a link to the site: http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

I post my javascript for parallax on:
http://pastie.org/5024950

The problem is, that it works just the opposit. On my desktop pc I have no parallax and on the mobile devices it is! What do I have to change so it works the opposit way?

Thanks already.

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution?

Answer (score 0):

The following article from Viget should cover your requirements.

[Managing JavaScript on Responsive Websites](http://viget.com/inspire/managing-javascript-on-responsive-websites)

Answer (score 0):

I find the parallax effect doesn't work that good on iOS devices including iPads because of the way scrolling is registered at the end of the scroll and not during. So screen size doesn't really work as a check.